# When exactly does the FOMC release the new calendar dates?

Tags: interest-rates, fomc

Please let me know if this is the appropriate place to post this.

I know every year the federal reserve releases the calendar dates for the next year's meetings around May or June. Is there a specific time that they always release it? Is it possible to figure out the exact time that they released previous calendars?

This is the page that they update the calendar:
https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the press releases. Bloomberg should have all of them.

E.g. the last press release was 11th May 2017:
https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/pressreleases/monetary20170511b.htm

> FOMC sets tentative 2018 meeting schedule The Federal Open Market
>   Committee, the monetary policy-setting arm of the Federal Reserve, on
>   Thursday announced its tentative meeting schedule covering 2018 and
>   going into 2019.
>
> The committee's two-day policy meetings are currently scheduled as
>   follows:
>
> Jan. 30-31; March 20-21; May 1-2; June 12-13; July 31-Aug. 1; Sept.
>   25-26; Nov. 7-8; Dec. 18-19; and Jan. 29-30, 2019. The Federal Reserve
>   Board chair is scheduled to deliver quarterly news conferences
>   following the March, June, September and December meetings.
>
> The FOMC next meets June 13-14, and four more times before the end of
>   the year: July 25-26, Sept. 19-20, Oct. 31-Nov. 1 and Dec. 12-13.
>
> Following its policy-setting meeting earlier this month, the FOMC left
>   the federal funds target rate unchanged at a range of 0.75 to 1
>   percent, but it did indicate that it is on track for an interest rate
>   hike in June.

Comment: The previous one was announced on June 28 2016 https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/pressreleases/monetary20160628a.htm By induction ;) you can see that they usually announce around May or June